# Deploy with Jenkins to VPN

Tags: jenkins, deployment, vpn, automated-deploy

My general goal is to automate deployment to a server in a VPN. Currently the VPNs are Cisco AnyConnect and Barracuda, but a more universal solution would be nice.

I thought about using Jenkins, but the only relevant resource that I found is this plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/OpenConnect+Plugin , which might solve the problem for AnyConnect but not for Barracuda.

I woud prefer Jenkins but I am opened for any other free tool that is better suited for this job.

Answer (score 2):

On linux (debian based)

```
sudo apt-get install openconnect
```

Add the following lines to the bottom of /etc/sudoers (ubuntu configuration)

```
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/openconnect*
jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/kill*
```

The you will get an option in the Jenkins run task called:

```
Connect to Cisco AnyConnect VPN
```