# Jenkins Openconnect plugin or other way connect to VPN in a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, vpn

I've got a task to setup a Jenkins pipeline that has to push images to a docker registry placed in another network. So I need to be able to establish a VPN connection. I stumbled upon Jenkins [Openconnect plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/openconnect-plugin) which is not supported (?) any more and had been removed from Jenkins' plugin repo. I've built the plugin and successfully install it using *.hpi file but I can't find neither documentation nor settings in order to understand how to use it. I use a scripted pipeline and I think I will need to write code like this:

```
withOpenConnect(["host=8.8.8.8", "login=username", "password=pass"]){
   pushDockerImages()
}
```

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151072/deploy-with-jenkins-to-vpn/43357784#43357784) but can't quite understand how to apply it in my case.

Maybe there is another way to deploy artifacts to another network nowadays and this plugin is just not compatible at all?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I'm supposed to add a Freestyle project with a build step called "Connect to Cysco VPN". After this I have to use another build step "Execute Shell" which will push artifacts to the remote repository.

Another question is how to squeeze all of it in my ansible playbook and JCasC configuration in order to keep this in code...